# Consultas con codigo VBA Acess

Tags: ms-access

hola necesito que mi consulta se busque por dni, pero lo estoy haciendo con modulo ya que es lo que tengo que usar no se si lo estaré haciendo bien adjunto el codigo:

```
Public Function buscardni() As String  
End Function
---------------------------------------
Sub buscar()
    buscardni = dni
End Sub
```

y en el criterio del dni debe aparecer buscardni()

no se si me di a entender.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Tu código no tiene nada que ver con lo que pides. Solo declaras una variable y ya. Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: gracias amigo lo tomare en cuenta, la verdad soy nuevo y le estoy dando horas a esto, capaz mas adelante vere los frutos.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que la función buscardni() tiene un contenido que no estás mostrando, ¿no?
¿Podrías poner el código?

Por otra parte, en el sub buscar() estás intentando asociarle a la función buscardni() una variable llamada dni. Si lo que quieres es rellenar la variable dni con el resultado de la función buscardni() la asignación debe ser a la inversa, es decir:

dni = buscardni()